# How do i bold one item in the WordPress menu

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm using elementor and I would like to bold only one item in the menu **( START HERE )** so that it stand out from the rest of the items. This is the site I'm referring to https://whichwine.tmmbuilds.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nav.elementor-nav-menu--main > ul > li:first-child > a {font-weight: bold !important;}
```